# Moving files from computer to computer with Nuendo.

Tags: nuendo, file

Hi, I really hope someone can help me out here!

Basically we recorded a song at my friends house, and I put it on my usb to bring it home and mix it. Everything shows up, all the tracks and the wav forms. BUT! my asio meter is maxed out. It plays but very very choppy and, well almost inaudible. No matter how much I play with the buffer size and latency compensations the meter won't even come down a percentage.

Obviously I am working on a different device (M-Audio ultra FROM a tubefire), but that shouldn't effect it like this could it?

if anyone has an idea it woul be greatly, greatly appreciated. thank you!

Comment: What asio driver do you have on your machine, asio media or asio 4 all? if you're on asio media try installing asio 4 all.

Comment: Are you opening the original session or making a new one and importing the files? It's entirely possible that the session was recorded at a setting your interface can't handle. Also, are you streaming from an external drive? You might want to move it to a native/internal drive if you're doing playback from the external drive you copied it to. There's so many variables it's not even funny.

Comment: turns out my computer couldn't take it. my cpu was hitting the roof..figured it out after deleting half tracks.

Answer (score 1):

Try muting (or deleting) most of the tracks and see if your system behaves better.  If it does, you may need to do something to improve performance (better HD, buffer sizes, driver check, fewer plugs).

If not, then you might have a system setup problem (driver check, I/O issues, project settings, etc)

good luck

Comment: ya you nailed it. the cpu demand was too much. that being said, i'm surprised my computer couldn't handle it. i've put this vaio through hell and back lol but i guess 25 plus tracks with plugs is too much.